# How to Change Checkbox/Radibutton Color in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have implemented Radio button and Checkbox control in my application using custom rendering. I have rendered the control by referring the below link. The controls default color is white. Since my application background color is white controls are not visible. I tried to change the color of the controls. But it is not working. Text color only changing. Can anyone suggest how to change the color of Checkbox/Radio button controls?

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set **Xamarin.Forms control** (like Switch) color from renderer with using below line code in **OnElementChanged** method:

```
Control.OnTintColor = Color.Blue.ToUIColor();
```

for your **XLab control**, you need to set background color in CheckBoxRenderer and change color in **OnElementChanged** method. or you can change from control also.

```
BackgroundColor = Element.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
```

**For Android** you can manage by material design like:

Create a new style.xml file with this (Change the color in colorAccent to whatever you like) and put it inside the Resources folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#0000FF</item>
        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then add an attribute to your MainActivity.cs to load that theme.

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```